# How to scroll down on a web page? [Power Automate]

Tags: javascript, power-automate, power-platform

I am building a flow on power automate that goes to a website reads the data and then extracts to excel, but I don't know how to tell the flow that the page needs to be scrolled to show more results.

I have tried to use a java script functions but it seems that the flow just don't use it while is recording the web site.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to do di something like this?
document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollHeight. If not, try to be more specific.

Comment: I can't give a lot of technical details because I am really not much into javascript, but basically I need that the flow understands that the page needs to be scroll down "infinitly" while reading the data. I will try this function that you've mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You will need to access the page manually, first, to ascertain the API pulls, then grab the information that it's pushing to the page directly through an HTTP connector.

1. Open the page in your browser, open the dev tools, and go to the 'Network' tab.
2. Refresh the page, and hopefully you'll be able identify the initial push of information which is sometimes client side.
3. Then scroll down, and look at what pops up that isn't media of some kind.

Quite often sites will populate more information via JSON code (which is perfect for Power Automate) and once you've identified where that comes from you can then make the calls yourself from an HTTP connector in the flow. Hopefully that will be the case here, otherwise, look up other methods (like XML) for more information on how to process it.

You'll need to pay attention to the 'Request' that is sent in order to know what to call in your flow. Plus for any given request the XHR section of Dev Tools also helps here.

There's a few articles online about this stuff, it's worth a StartPage search on finding client side API calls.

Answer (score 0):

In some browser automation flows, you may need to scroll on web pages to make specific elements visible on the screen.
Power Automate allows scrolling on web pages through two different approaches. The first one requires the Focus text field on web page action, while the second requires JavaScript scripting.
To scroll to a specific element on a web page, you can deploy the Focus text field on web page action. Apart from the Focus text field on web page action, you can scroll on web pages using JavaScript. To run JavaScript on web pages, use the Execute Javascript function on web page action. In this video you will find out more details: https://youtu.be/jWIDr9tW9hQ

Answer (score 0):

Since your page has infinite scroll, you need to use the 'Focus text field' action. You have to set up this action inside a loop. So that you are able to scroll down as much as you need.

You can find more details about the above action at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/how-to/scroll-web-page